# Create a range from values of a list in loop

Tags: python, list, range

I have a list that is being appended in a loop from the different files (file_1, file_2, ..)  I have.I initiate the list with zero to because I need to create a range that will start with 1:

```
a =  [0]    #here is the zero value created
a = [0, 8]  #here is the list after open file 1
a = [0, 8, 20]     #here is the list after open file 2
a = [0, 8, 20, 23] #here is the list after open file 3
....
```

I need to create a range (my output) as this:

```
file_1 = 1 - 8
file_2 = 9 - 28   #basically, ('the previous last element + 1' - 'the sum of the list')
file_3 = 29 - 51
...
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no attempt at solving this from author

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
range(sum(a[:-1]), sum(a))
```

Comment: can just simple use your : sum(a[:-1]) + ' - ' + sum(a)

Comment: @gusa10, agreed, i think OP amended his post to clarify. in any case, the idea is there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean with "file 1" "file 2" etc. I suppose you mean there's a file called file 1?

```
files = ['file 1', 'file 2', 'file 3']
a = [0, 8, 20, 23]
for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    print('{} = {} - {}'.format(files[i],  a[i] + 1, a[i + 1]))
```